# Can we use selenium-webdriver and nokogiri together?

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, nokogiri, ruby-1.9.3

I used `Nokogiri` as below:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

# Get a Nokogiri::HTML::Document for the page we’re interested in...

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://www.google.com/search?q=sparklemotion'))
```

But my bad,due to company firewall may be, I am getting error:

```
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:762:in `initialize': getaddrinfo: No such
host is known.  (SocketError)
```

Thus I thought that I would use `selenium-webdriver` to navigate and `nokogiri` to work on webpage source `html`.

```
require "rubygems"
require "selenium-webdriver"

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
driver.get "http://www.google.com/search?q=sparklemotion"
```

So here how would I give webpage content(html) to `nokogiri`?

Please suggest me here.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can get the source of the page from selenium-webdriver by using the [`page_source`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/rb/Selenium/WebDriver/Driver.html#page_source-instance_method) method:

```
driver.page_source
```

So your script could be:

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'
require 'nokogiri'

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
driver.get "http://www.google.com/"

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(driver.page_source)
# Do whatever with nokogiri
```

That said, I do not know why you would want to use nokogiri instead of just selenium-webdriver.

Comment: Thank you very much to confirm me what i was looking for. `+1` to you!

Comment: +1, and the reason is to use the beautiful css selector of nokogiri.

Comment: One reason is that Selenium is extremely slow at things like: `session.all(div.getme)` when you are working with a big document. Nokogiri is lightning fast in comparison. I use your suggested approach to log in to a buggy ASP.NET site with Selenium, fetch the source and process tags with Nokogiri.